# Can multiple abilities be used at once if they have a shared prerequisite?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, powers, fighter

Greater Vital Strike, Spirited Charge, and Unstoppable Strike (19th level Weapon Master).

Or Greater Vital Strike, Greater Power Attack, Piledriver, and Overhand chop.

Do these all work at once or do I have to choose?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Nice question, have a +1 from me. Anyway, you should take a look at our [Tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about/), and when you get 20 rep, feel free to join us in the [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat).

Answer (score 11):

First, just a bit of terminology: “Ability” in *Pathfinder* refers to Strength, Dexterity, Constitution, Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma. The details you list are “Feats” or “Class Features.”

Whether or not two Feats share a prerequisite is irrelevant here; you must meet the prerequisite to choose and use a Feat, but two Feats that have the same prerequisite aren’t necessarily related in any way beyond that shared prerequisite.

As for whether things can be used together, that depends on how they are worded. It’s a case-by-case thing.

#### Power Attack

For instance, (Greater) Power Attack modifies an attack; any time you attack, you can choose to use it. So that combines with everything else you have listed.

#### Spirited Charge

Spirited Charge modifies a charge attack, specifically, which also involves an attack so you can use Power Attack at the same time (but when not charging you cannot use Spirited Charge).

#### Vital Strike

(Greater) Vital Strike requires that you use the “attack action,” which is kind of misleading because that sounds like “an attack” but it’s not: it’s actually a specific form of Standard Action. As a Standard Action, it cannot be used as the same time as a Charge (and therefore cannot be combined with Spirited Charge) because a Charge requires a Full-Round Action. In other words, if you have both Vital Strike and Spirited Charge, you can Attack for double damage from Vital Strike, or Charge for double damage from Spirited Charge, but there’s no way to do both at the same time. But since Power Attack modifies any attack, it can be used alongside either (and it would be doubled by either).

#### Piledriver and Unstoppable Strike

Piledriver and Unstoppable Strike are yet more separate options: they are new Standard Actions, not the Attack Action, so Vital Strike does not apply, and it is not a Charge, so Spirited Charge does not apply. Power Attack could if you wanted.

#### Overhand Chop

Now, Overhand Chop doubles either a single attack or a charge, that is, it doubles the same things that Vital Strike or Spirited Charge would. Therefore, they can be combined. However, note that you do not get double your doubled damage (i.e. 4×). Instead, the rules state that you add up the multiples. You normally get 1× your damage, and something that doubles it adds another 1× (total 2×). When you have two things that double, each each adds 1×, so you get a total of 3× (1× for base damage, +1× for Overhand Chop, +1× for Vital Strike or Spirited Charge). With Greater Vital Strike (a 4× multiplier, or +3× over your usual 1×), you would get 1× (base) + 1× (Overhand Chop) + 3× (Greater Vital Strike), for a total of 5×.